# Use STUFF function to bring only those values which match the column in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a stuff function as:

```
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(id as varchar)
       FROM users 
       WHERE userID = depatments.userID 
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Users
```

Every user has one department, I want to return those values of users table which match that department but instead it is returning all values of all rows in this column. How can I fix it?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. Especially if you provided sample data as DDL/DML for us to test.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? The only thing `STUFF` does is remove the leading `,`. String Aggregation is performed by `XML PATH()`. SQL Server 2017 introduced `STRING_AGG` so XML Path is no longer necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, my guess is that users has `id`, but not `userid`.  So:

```
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(id as varchar(255))
       FROM users u
       WHERE u.id = departments.userID 
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, ''
     ) AS Users
```

Notes:

- *Never* use `varchar` (or related types) without a length.  SQL Server has default lengths that vary by context and may not be big enough.
- *Always* qualify all column references in a query, so it is clear where they come from.  If you use `u.userid - departments.userId` in your query, then you would have gotten an error and just fixed the code.
- Use table aliases so queries are easier to write and to read.

Comment: this is where i am getting all values in that users row, it will not bring the matched results but everything all rows are populated with tons of ids and al are same for all rows